# Pandas join is slow

Tags: pandas

edit at Oct 16 2017: I think I found the problem, it seems to be a bug in pandas core. It can't merge/join anything over 145k rows. 144k rows it can do without an issue. Pandas version 0.20.3, running on Fedora 26.

----Original post----

I have a medium size amount of data to process (about 200k rows with about 40 columns). I've optimised a lot of the code, but the only trouble I have now is joining the columns.

I receive the data in an unfortunate structure and need to extract the data in a certain way, then put it all into a dataframe.

Basically I extract 2 arrays at a time (each 200k rows long). One array is the timestamp, the other array is the values.

Here I create a dataframe, and use the timestamp as the index.

When I extract the second block of data, I do the same and create a new dataframe using the new values + timestamp.

I need to join the two dataframes on the index. The timestamps can be slightly different, so I use a join method using the 'outer' method, to keep the new timestamps. Basically I follow the documentation below.

result = left.join(right, how='outer')

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#joining-on-index

This however is way to slow. I left it for about 15 mins and it still hadn't finished processing, so I killed the process.

Can anyone help? Any hints/tips?

edit:
It's a work thing, so I can't give out the data sorry. But it's just two long dataframes, each with a timestamp as the index, and a single column for the values.

The code is just as described above.
data_df.join(variable_df, how='outer')

Comment: There might be better methods to do what you want. Obviously, nothing more can be said without your DATA or an explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: What happens when you leave the timestamp as a string or float (whatever you receive it as) and merge on that?

Comment: Try using dictionary, if you just want to combine something that seems like a key-value pair.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to answer this. It's not really a bug in pandas.

The timestamp was a nanosecond timestamp, and joining them on the index like this was causing a massive slow down. Basically it was better to join on a column - made it all much faster.